# Fragments aren't replacing properly in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm going to develop an android app to use `Fragments` with a `ViewPager` using the `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I'm trying to replace fragments `onClick` of a button inside a fragment but when I click on that button, the current layout goes up and next layout still comes on that position i.e.2 layouts come on a single fragment and I don't want it.

I'm using these steps to replace but not getting changed properly,

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.select_program_root, newFrag);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Even I'm using `TabHost` with `ViewPager` inside a horizontal `ScrollView`. Everything is fine in my app. I'm only stuck on replacing of fragments `onClick` of buttons which are located inside fragments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using getChildFragmentManager() ?

Comment: Nope. Is it also use to replace fragments? If yes post your sample code.

Comment: getChildFragmentManager() returns a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment (Google documentation).  You use it the same way as getSupportFragmentManager(). `FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity()
                    .getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.select_program_root, newFrag);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();`

Comment: Can you tell me a thing? select_program_root is the linearlayout of my fragment1. Should I mention this name in each fragment?

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager()` is undefined for FragmentActivity.

Comment: the id you put as the first parameter of replace() is the id of the container in which the child fragment will be placed. So the child fragments don't need any information about their placement, the manager will take care of it.

Comment: but still its not working.

Comment: Why has it been downvoted? If you have solution give it instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by implementing few lines of code.

Create this method into your `FragmentActivity`:

```
public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}
```

And call it `onClick` of a Fragment:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(3, true);
```